# Question on probability with respect to dice throwing

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, dice

I encountered this question while solving few practice problems on probability theory. I have solved it in my own way, but am unsure about whether it's the correct way to go about it.

> Four fair dice are thrown. One of them shows a six. Find the probability
>   that only one die shows a six.

My approach: 
$$
\begin{align*}
P\big(\text{only 1 six}\big|\text{at least 1 six}\big) 
&= \frac{P(\text{only 1 six}, \text{ at least one six})}{P(\text{at least 1 six})} \\ 
&= \frac{P(\text{only 1 six})}{P(\text{at least 1 six}) }
\end{align*}
$$

Now, $P(\text{at least 1 six}) = 1 - \frac{5^3}{6^3}$
and $P(\text{only 1 six}) = ({}_{4}C_1) \frac{1}{6}$ $\frac{5^3}{6^3}$.

**So, substituting, I get $\frac{500}{671}$ as my answer.**

Is my approach correct?
Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: When it says "one of them shows a six," does that mean (a) one of the four dice is examined, and it proves to have rolled a six, or (b) all four of the dice are examined, and at least one of them happens to have rolled a six?  These are different events.

Comment: It means (b). All are examined.

Comment: Your approach and final answer are okay then. Not okay is $P(\text{at least 1 six}) = 1 - \frac{5}{6^3}$ and $P(\text{only 1 six}) = ({}_{4}C_1) \frac{1}{6}$ $\frac{5}{6^3}$. They should be $P(\text{at least 1 six}) = 1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$ and $P(\text{only 1 six}) = ({}_{4}C_1) \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$. Because your final answer is okay I suspect they are typos.

Comment: Yes, I fixed them now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Problem}$. Four dice are thrown. One of them shows a six. Find the probability that only one die shows a six.

$\textbf{Solution}$. Since we know in advance that one of the four dice shows a six, we need to use conditional probability.

Let $A$ be the event that at least one of the four dice shows a six, and let 
$B$ be the event that exactly one of the four dice shows a six. Since the outcomes in $B$ are contained in the event $A$, we have $B\cap A = B$.

To find $P(A)$, let's find $P(A')$, where $A'$ is the event that no die shows a six ($A'$ is the complement of $A$). Since $P(A')=(5/6)^4$ using a counting technique, 
$$
P(A)=1-P(A') = \boxed{1-(5/6)^4}.
$$
Now, to find $P(B)$, we'll use the binomial probability distribution: 
$$
b(x;n,p) = 
\begin{cases}
\binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x} &\mbox{ if }x = 0,1,2,\ldots, n, \\ 
\qquad\quad  0 & \mbox{ otherwise},  
\end{cases} 
$$
where $n$ is the number of trials and $p$ is the probability of success.

In this setting, $n=4$, $p=1/6$, and $x=1$. 
So 
$$
P(B) = b(1; 4,1/6)= \binom{4}{1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^1\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{3} =\boxed{\frac{125}{324}}. 
$$
Putting this together, we have 
$$
P(B|A) = \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(B)}{P(A)} = \color{green}{\boxed{\frac{500}{671}}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the help.